# What does this notation mean?

Tags: standard-model, terminology

Terminology question.

Reading [this](http://bolvan.ph.utexas.edu/%7Evadim/classes/11f/SM.pdf), in the middle of the second page, when it says

> Left-handed quarks form 3 (3; 2; +
> 1
> 6
> ) multiplets Qn (n = 1; 2; 3);

What does this (3;2;+1/6) mean?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68484/2451

Answer (score 0):

It labels irreducible representations of the standard model group $SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68484/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41424/2451) Phys.SE posts.